# Extracting information from files

Tags: python

I have a file, the content is in the format of

```
41545
0
0
1
2
3
3
3
...
```

Following is the code

```
X=[]
Y=[]
total=0
count=0
for line in open(file,'r'):
    count+=1
    line=line.strip()
    if(line.strip()):
        if(count==1):
            total=int(line)
        else:
            X.append(count-1)
            Y.append(int(line))
```

the output for the above code is

```
total=41545 #first line
X=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7] #count of second line onwards
Y=[0,0,1,2,3,3,3] #second line onwards information
```

Is there a shorter and hopefully more efficient code that can achieve the same purpose?

Answer (score 3):

Build a generator over the file to return just `int`s, then transpose the `enumeration` to get your `X` and `Y`, eg:

```
with open('testing.txt') as fin:
    lines = (int(line) for line in fin)
    total = next(lines)
    X, Y = zip(*enumerate(lines, 1))
```

Note X and Y will be tuples instead of lists, but you can convert them after if you wish.

Comment: clean and efficient

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick. Read the first line by itself and convert to `int`. Then read the remaining lines via list comprehension. Then you can just generate the line numbers based on the number of values read in.

```
with open(file, 'r') as f:
    total = int(f.readline().strip())
    Y = [int(i) for i in f.readlines()]
    X = list(range(1,len(Y)+1))
```

Comment: This is great, except that readlines() is not efficient and I think you swapped X and Y.

Comment: Oops I did indeed flip X and Y.

Answer (score 0):

There certainly is!

Try this:

```
Y=[]

with open(file, 'r') as fd:
    total = int(fd.readline().strip())

    for line in fd:
        line=line.strip()
        if(line):
            Y.append(int(line))
```

X is superfluous because it my be calculated by

```
pos = 4 #Index of an element in Y
y_value = Y[pos]
x_value = pos + 1 #X value of that element
```

Where pos is the index of an element of Y that you would like the X value for